# Retrieving JavaScript source file location?

Tags: javascript

If I load a JavaScript source file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="src/file.js"></source>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is that how could `file.js` know that the relative path to its location is `src/`? I need this information for building up a URL from the source file that depends on the URL it was loaded from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="src/file.js" id="script0"></script>
```

In file.js:

```
var path = document.getElementById ( "script0" ).getAttribute ( "src" );
```

Comment: I just thought about it myself too :). I'll just get all script elements, loop through them and use a simple regex replace to take the relative path (if the src matched).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `getAttribute` you'll get the written src. If you use the `.src` attribute, you'll get the src with current location.

http://jsbin.com/igixi5/5/